# Conditionally setting value of a DOM element

Tags: jquery

Is the following possible to do?

```
$("#textarea1").val = function() {
    $.each(data, function(i, j) {
        if ($.trim($("#text2").val()) == j.l) {
            return j.v;
        } else {}
    });
};
```

Can we conditionally set the value of some input type or div?

Comment: Would `$("#textarea1").val(j.v); return false;` work instead of your `return` statement, and removing the `.val` assignment? I'm not fully sure how your loop is supposed to function.

Comment: awesome man... it was right there infront of the eyes... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have some valid desgin-pattern reason for not simply calling `$("#textarea1").val(j.v)` inside your `each` function, instead of setting it externally to the function as you do now. (Perhaps you have many function objects whose logic you wish to use conditionally to set a large collection of inputs?)

That said, your code just needs a few changes:

1. Use the `val` function correctly (it's a setter, not a settable property).
2. Right now, the `return` statement is terminating the function passed to `each`, not the outer function.  You should have the `each` function set a variable and then break by returning false.

It should look something like:

```
$("#textarea1").val(function() {
    var result;
    $.each(data, function(i, j) {
        ...
        result = j.v;
        return false;
    });
    return result;
});
```

`val` will automatically execute the function and use the return value.

Answer (score 1):

**You should find out the value first, then change the value of the element.**

Your doing it in a very strange way. Im not really sure what your doing with your loop. But do this first, then set the elements value.

Quick example:

```
var name = "Sam!";

if ( name != "Sam!" ) {
  $("#textarea1").val("Your not Sam!");
} else {
  $("#textarea1").val("Hey Sam :)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `condition` evaluates to `true`, then the value will be set to `"yes"`. Otherwise it reamins unchanged.

```
$("#textarea1").val(function(i, oldval) {
    return condition ? "yes" : oldval;
});
```